# Can I disable/enable a trigger based on object_id, or without using its name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

Is there a way to write something like

`DISABLE TRIGGER WHERE object_id = x`

or another way not to hardcode the trigger's name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @obj sysname = object_name(xxx);
declare @sql varchar(4000) = 'disable trigger ' + @obj
exec(@sql)
```

?